# how to download font file when page loads first time in jsf2

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am developing an jsf2.2 application where, i have put some fonts files on server side a login screen on that application, when user log in successfully i want to download some fonts file to client side path(`C:\Windows\Fonts`) so that user can have same fonts which are used in application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use css for this. Paste this code at the start of your css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  src: url( "HelveticaNeue-Light.woff.jsf?ln=css" ) format("truetype");
}
```

In this specific case the woff file placed in the reasources/css folder.

Comment: It's a font [file extension](http://www.fileinfo.com/filetypes/font). You can use any of them.

Comment: the fonts will automatically save into this path(`C:\Windows\Fonts`) ??

Comment: Well, actually no. It depends on the browser, but usually they only store it in the RAM. But if you put this code into your page's css, the browser will be able to use that font family on that page.
Is there a specific reason you want to see this font under C:\Windows\Fonts ?

Comment: in my page i am using 3,2 fonts so i ve to create 3,2 `@font-face` for different fonts ??

Comment: Yes. Note: usually designers does not recommend to use more than one font style on a page.

Comment: could you tell me reason of that?